# Time comparison in Apex

Tags: apex, time

I have below code

```
Time startTime = objAvailableTime.StartTime;
                Time endTime = objAvailableTime.EndTime;
                List<Time> lstTime = new List<Time>();
                while(startTime < endTime){
                    lstTime.add(startTime);
                    startTime = startTime.addHours(apptDuration);
                    System.debug('start time and end time is'+startTime + ' '+endTime);
                }
```

The issue here I am facing is if my `endTime` is at 11pm at night and my `startTime` is at 6pm and `apptDuration` is 2 hours then it always remains in the loop and errors out. This is happening because at 12am time becomes 00:00 and it continues in the loop. Is there an efficient way to compare two times and increment till the end?

Comment: You have to use datetime field because it is not the same compare 2017-11-20T20:00:00 with 2017-11-21T00:00:00. In this case 00:00:00 is greater that 20:00:00

Comment: I cannot use DateTime Field.

Comment: it would be important to mention that in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use the `Datetime` type here despite your comments to the contrary. If you need a `List<Time>`, you can call `time()` on each instance (similar to `date()`, `year()`, etc.).

```
Datetime pointer, max;
pointer = Datetime.newInstance(Date.today(), objAvailableTime.StartTime);
max = (objAvailableTime.EndTime < objAvailableTime.StartTime) ?
    Date.newInstance(Date.today().addDays(1), objAvailableTime.EndTime) :
    Date.newInstance(Date.today(), objAvailableTime.EndTime);

List<Time> times = new List<Time>();
while (pointer < max)
{
    times.add(pointer.time());
    pointer = pointer.addHours(apptDuration);
}
```

If you are *certain* that the `EndTime` is strictly greater than `StartTime`, you can just use today as the `Date` component of both `newInstance` calls:

```
Datetime pointer = Datetime.newInstance(Date.today(), objAvailableTime.StartTime);
Datetime max = Date.newInstance(Date.today(), objAvailableTime.EndTime);
```

Comment: My start time is 8:00 am and end time is 11pm with 2 hour duration in that case at 10pm when i add 2 hours it becomes 00:00 and it is still less than 11pm and loop continues.

Comment: That's why you use `Datetime` values...midnight tomorrow is greater than 11PM today.